# Swift tableview 'method heightForHeaderInSection' makes section text raise

Tags: swift, uitableview

When heightForHeaderInSection and/or heightForFooterInSection  is called, the section text raises above it's first row. I attached a screenshot to show the issue. How can I increase the section spacing without the section header being affected?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let fruits = 
["apple","pear","orange","caramel","peach","fruit","fruits"]
let numbers = ["1", "2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection 
section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return fruits.count
    } else {
        return numbers.count
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 {
        return "Animals"
    } else {
        return "Numbers"
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
"cell1", for: indexPath)
    
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruits[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.textLabel?.text = numbers[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
    
}
```

These are the 2 methods in question:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection 
section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

[image: Red arrows indicate the unwanted space.]

Comment: Can you paste your table view code in the question?

Comment: @Jake The code is added.

Comment: Comment out the `heightForHeaderInSection` function.

Comment: You're setting it to 100. That's what is causing the gap.

Comment: If you want to increase the spacing, I would instead intercept the first cell and modify that cell.

Comment: @Jake I want to have a custom space between the sections ( eg.100 points ). It's working, just the section text is also being moved higher.

Comment: @Jake I got it to work. Use tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 100

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the height of the header to 100.  See here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection 
section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100 // Instead try returning 30
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection 
section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 100 // If you are not using a footer - return .zero
}
```

Comment: I actually want 100 points between the Foot of the 'Fruits' section and the 'Numbers' section. ( the code is working, it's just the 'Numbers' text is also raised for some reason.

Comment: @VidalSingh Then you would want your heightForHeaderInSection to be around 30 in height, and then leave your heightForFooterInSection at 100

Comment: I got it to work. Use tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 100

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from another post.

Just add:

### tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 100 // or whatever number you want.

There's also another way.

Click on of these ->

[image: tableView style]

You can choose Grouped or the rounded design 'Inset Grouped'

After you can use the method 'heightForHeaderInSection' to select the specific section/s.